Bash array has many elements and just one at the same time
I am trying to get a list of all collections in Mongo database. It seems successful at first, but the contents of allCollections variable seemed weird to me, because I couldn't get elements separately
allCollections=$(mongosh "${sourceConnectionString}" --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(name) { print(name);})")
root@ce679cd166d0:/app# echo ${allCollections[1]}

root@ce679cd166d0:/app# echo ${#mapped[@]} 
1

That's why I decided to reassign it to another array, which should be normal, like that
mapped=()
while read -r c
do
  echo $c
  echo "another one"
  mapped+="${c}"
done <<< "${allCollections}"
echo ${#mapped[@]}

the output
root@ce679cd166d0:
GameSessionBonuses
another one
TurnoversByTransactionsHourly
another one
InteractionTokens
another one
TurnoversAllowedGameTypes
another one
AuthTokens
another one
.....
1

So nothing changed. The loop says that there are multiple separate elements, but somehow it's still just one element. I have no idea what's actually inside mapped or allCollections and how to properly check it.

mapped+="${c}" should probably be mapped+=("${c}").

As Toby said -- your current code is appending to item 0, not adding new array items.

declare -p mapped allCollections is an easy way to print the actual value of both variables in unambiguous form.

And the original assignment is to a scalar allCollections - you want allCollections=($(mongosh …)).

declare -p mapped would be a better way of printing the content of mapped but your problems all stem from creating allCollections as a scalar instead of an array. [edit] your question to describe the format of and show us sample output of mongosh "${sourceConnectionString}" --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(name) { print(name);})") and show us what you need your final output to be given that input so we can help you. Make sure your [mcve] covers rainy day cases too, not just sunny day, so you don't end up with a solution that fails for rainy day cases.

@TobySpeight, ...ideally they shouldn't want allCollections=($(...)) -- it runs afoul of BashPitfalls #50.

Yes, readarray is a better choice.

Indeed; readarray -t allCollections < <(...) is the general Right Thing.

readarray is a fantastic command, saved me so many lines and loops already, thank you
